# Is process-pinning like with Intel-MPI possible in OpenMPI?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, intel-mpi

With Intel-MPI I can pin the MPI processes started by `mpirun` to a certain cores on a node.
For example with 24 cores and Intel-MPI:

```
mpirun -np 12 -genv I_MPI_PIN_PROCESSOR_LIST=0-11 ./some.exe &
mpirun -np 12 -genv I_MPI_PIN_PROCESSOR_LIST=12-23 ./other.exe &
```

With OpenMPI there is the option `--bind-to` with one these arguments: none, hwthread, core, l1cache, l2cache, l3cache, socket, numa, board.

I noticed that `--bind-to socket` binds process 0 to socket 0 and process 1 to socket 1, and so on. This is bad, since for best communication between `some.exe` processes, all of them should be on one socket and `other.exe` processes should be on the other socket.

Is there no equivalent pin option in OpenMPI?

Comment: try `mpirun --cpu-set 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 ./some.exe`

Comment: does not work as ``` --report-bindings ``` tells me then 
```MCW rank 0 is not bound (or bound to all available processors)
MCW rank 1 is not bound (or bound to all available processors)
``` and so on

Comment: the binding report could be wrong here ... try `mpirun --tag-output ... grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status` to confirm how tasks are pinned.

Comment: you can also give a try to the `--map-by core` option. Use `--map-by core --bind-to socket` instead if you only want to pin on sockets instead of cores.

Comment: ```--map-by l2cache``` is the closest I found. It assigns all ranks to the same l2cache/socket. But if I run another mpirun command, it assigns the same processors again -> inefficient. Anyway I found it to work good enough without process pinning.

Comment: Two `mpirun` "instances" are independent and have no knowledge of each other, so yes, both jobs will end up time sharing. Consider using a resource manager such as Slurm in order to prevent this.